# Find the href of a link within a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the HTML:

```
<th width="90px" class="navigation" scope="col">
    <a href="1234">BLOG</a>
</th>
```

I am wanting to find the href when I click on `BLOG`

I have tried this:

```
$('.navigation').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor behavior
    var goTo = this.child().getAttribute("href"); // store anchor href

    alert(goTo);
});
```

There are also other links on the page that I don't want to alert the href. Otherwise I would have done this:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor behavior
    var goTo = this.getAttribute("href"); // store anchor href

    alert(goTo);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BjDbJ/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.navigation a , .differentclass a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor behavior
    var goTo = $(this).attr("href"); // store anchor href

    alert(goTo);
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to then do it to another class like `<th width="90px" class="differentclass" scope="col"><a href="1r434">yo</a></th>` So that only links within `navigation` and `differentclass` alert the href?

Comment: Else other use common class for all th tag it is the  best way

Comment: Now your scenario i edited the answer please check and let me know you have any issues

Answer (score 2):

change this:

```
var goTo = this.child().getAttribute("href");
```

to this:

```
var goTo = this.children.item('a').getAttribute('href');
```

#### [Fiddle in action](http://jsfiddle.net/z33m6/)

or with jQuery way:

```
var goTo = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/)**:

```
$('.navigation').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor behavior
    var goTo = $(this).children().attr("href"); // store anchor href

    alert(goTo);
});
```

or **[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)**:

```
$('.navigation').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default anchor behavior
    var goTo = $(this).find('a').attr("href"); // store anchor href

    alert(goTo);
});
```

Also, you can use `.attr('href')` instead of `getAttribute("href");` to get the `href` value of your anchor.

Answer (score 1):

use `.attr()`:

```
 $(this).attr("href");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BjDbJ/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.navigation').click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var goTo = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
   alert(goTo)
});
```

works for me

Comment: OP says: "There are also other links on the page that I don't want to alert the href. Otherwise I would have done this" - which is why this solution is not used.

Answer (score 0):

`<th width="90px" class="navigation" scope="col">
    <a href="1234" class="link1">BLOG</a>
    <a href="5678">BLOG2</a>
</th>`

Adding to @Jai's answer, if you want the href of a particular link within a class, the you can  use this -
`var goTo = $(this).find('a.link1').attr('href');`

or even this

`var goTo = $(this).find('.link1').attr('href');`